# How to use MongoDB Aggregations JSON String as argument "arg0" in Spring Data ChangeStreamOptions.builder().filter(arg0)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have implemented a *Reactive Async REST API* with *Spring Web Flux* and *MongoDB Change Streams*, which works correctly. But instead of passing an Aggregation object with Criteria to the `".filter(arg0)" method`, I would like to pass a M*ongoDB Aggregation JSON string* to the filter method, such like:

```
ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
        .filter(Document.parse("[{$match: {age: {$gt: 18}}}, {'operationType': 'insert'}]"))
        .returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build();
```

The code snippet above doesn't work because it's not correct.

Here is my working implementation below.
And the method

`public Flux<Person> watchAgeGreaterThan(Integer ageParam){...}`

is invoked through a REST endpoint `"/api/rest/age/greaterthan/{ageParam}"` to return the stream asynchronously, every time a Document is inserted in MongoDB `"person_collection"` and its "age" field is greater than "ageParam".

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ChangeStreamEvent;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ChangeStreamOptions;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;


@Service
public class Watch {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;


    public Flux<Person> watchAgeGreaterThan(Integer ageParam) {

        ChangeStreamOptions options = ChangeStreamOptions.builder()
            .filter(Aggregation.newAggregation(Person.class, 
                        Aggregation.match(
                            Criteria.where("operationType").is("insert")
                                .and("fullDocument.age").gt(ageParam)
                        ))
                    ).returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build();

        return reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("person_collection", options, Person.class)
                    .map(ChangeStreamEvent::getBody)
                    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error on 'person' change stream event :: " 
                                                    + throwable.getMessage(), throwable));
    }

}
```

I have tried also another different implementation, which you can see below:

```
public class CustomAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private String aggregationJsonString;

    public CustomAggregationOperation(String aggregationJsonString) {
        this.aggregationJsonString = aggregationJsonString;
    }

    @Override
    public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(Document.parse(aggregationJsonString));
    }
}


@Service
public class Watch {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;


    public Flux<Person> watchAgeGreaterThan(Integer ageParam) {
        String queryJsonString = "{$match: {age: {$gt: 18}}}";

        AggregationOperation matchOperationType = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("operationType").is("insert"));

        TypedAggregation<Person> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Person.class, 
                                                    matchOperationType, new CustomAggregationOperation(queryJsonString));

        ChangeStreamOptions options2 = ChangeStreamOptions.builder().filter(aggregation).returnFullDocumentOnUpdate().build();

        return reactiveMongoTemplate.changeStream("person_collection", options2, Person.class)
                    .map(ChangeStreamEvent::getBody)
                    .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Error on 'person' change stream event :: " 
                                                    + throwable.getMessage(), throwable));
    }
}
```

But this one doesn't work.